# How do I find the right gradient mix from looking at an image of a gradient?

Tags: css, button, gradient

I have the following image:

[image]

I need the proper gradient that can make this work but being new to css I can't figure it out.

Some colors I've tried playing with are:

6FBFC5
66BAC0
2F9BA3

i also used this tool: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: What issues are you having? The syntax or what colours/colour stops to pick?

Comment: Open image in favorite image editor, eyedropper on the very top pixel, eyedropper on the very bottom color, done.  It's very unlikely that image has 3 color stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty accurate:

```
    background: #6ec0c7; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #6ec0c7 0%, #62b5bc 50%, #58a9b1 99%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6ec0c7), color-stop(50%,#62b5bc), color-stop(99%,#58a9b1)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #6ec0c7 0%,#62b5bc 50%,#58a9b1 99%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #6ec0c7 0%,#62b5bc 50%,#58a9b1 99%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #6ec0c7 0%,#62b5bc 50%,#58a9b1 99%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #6ec0c7 0%,#62b5bc 50%,#58a9b1 99%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6ec0c7', endColorstr='#58a9b1',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

It uses 3 colour points from the original image. Without knowing the exact starting point and how many different single colours make up the above it is very difficult to recreate a 100% match. You shouldn't be able to tell the difference from the yours and mine by eye

Comment: Thanks! indeed this is close! I am still trying to be closer!